# Centralizer of $g$ has finite index $\iff$ $g$ belongs a finite normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ an arbitrary group and $g \in G$. I would like to prove that $|g|< +\infty$ and $|\{g^x: x \in G\}| =|G : C_G(g)|<+\infty$ if, and only if, exists a normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $g\in N$ and $|N|<+\infty$.

The converse is cleary trivial. For the first side, I'm trying to prove that $x \in G'$ and $|G:Z(G)|$ is finite (or the set of commutators is finite) and thus by Schur's Theorem (or the Neumann's Theorem), $|G'|$ is finite, but I'm not able to do this. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $|G:C_G(g)|$ is finite, there is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ with $|G:N|$ finite and $N \le C_G(g)$.

Let $M = \langle g^x : x \in G \rangle$ be the normal closure of $g$ in $G$. Then, since $N \unlhd G$, we have $g^x \in C_G(N)$ for all $x \in G$, so $M \le C_G(N)$ and hence $|M:C_G(M)|$ is finite, so $|M:Z(M)|$ is finite.

Note, by Schur's theorem $M'$ is finite. Also, since $M/M'$ is abelian and generated by finitely many elements of finite order, $M/M'$ is finite, so $M$ is finite.

Comment: Why $\dfrac{M}{M'}$ is generated by finitely many elements of finite order?

Comment: That is what we are assuming.

Comment: Well, this question is trivial if we use the Dietzmann's Lemma...